# Send an asset from a plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, assets, controller, assetfilemodel

I have a controller which fetches an asset from an entry (this is the service method that provides the asset):

```
public function findPoster($entryId) {
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->id = $entryId;

    $entry = $criteria->first();

    if ($entry) {
        if ($entry->downloadItem) {
            return $entry->downloadItem->first();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

That works great, however now I need to send the asset to the browser. Having a little poke around in the method listing I see there is a `CBaseController::renderFile()` which sounds to be what I need, however I can't work out the correct way to build a path to the file. Accessing `$url` from the asset I've fetched returns a public relative path but obviously I need the path on the filesystem.

---

So far I've got this working:

```
$name = strtolower($asset->title) . '.' . $asset->extension;

header('Content-Type: ' . $asset->getMimeType());
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);

$path = realpath(craft()->basePath . '/../../public/' . $asset->url);

die(file_get_contents($path));
```

However this is far from ideal because:

- I have to hardcode the `public` directory which isn't the case at any other point in Craft, so it feels really dirty.
- Manually setting the headers seems like something a controller method would be able to take care of properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a way to do this with `CBaseController::renderFile()`, but I'd just use [`craft()->request->sendFile()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#sendFile-detail).

The 3rd parameter is an optional `$options` array and you can pass a `'forceDownload' => true` as one of the key => value pairs to force it to download to the browser.

Instead of hardcoding the the path to your public assets folder, you can do something like:

```
$path = IOHelper::getFolderName(craft()->request->getScriptFile());
```

That should get you the path to the folder your public `index.php` file is executing in and you can tack on your public asset path from there.